# Pass value via Mongoose Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

I have `register.js` from where I'm exporting my functions to count the number of documents in a collection.

And another function utilises that function and I will make it do some additional task to it.

The problem here is, I'm getting the result in `console`, and not sure how to pass it via call back.

---

*register.js*

```
module.exports.getCount = function(){
  User.countDocuments({},function(err,count){
    console.log(count)    // WORKS FINE
    return count;         //Doesn't work
  })
}

module.exports.FB_updateUserID = function(facebookUserID, callback){
  this.getCount();

  return this.getCount(); //Doesn't work
}
```

*facebookLogin.js*

```
User.FB_updateUserID(req.body.facebookUserID, (err, updatedUser) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(updatedUser);    //THIS SHOWS UNDEFINED

});
```

I'm looking for the right way of doing it.

Comment: You are not returning the results. You have to return something.

Comment: I tried return as well, let me show you.

Comment: @Akrion, please check the update

Comment: but isn't `countDocuments` async call? You should be doing `const number = await User.count();` no?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess so, but it's weird as I'm getting it in console, which makes me feel that it's working correctly. But let me check if it's because of it's asynchronous nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because we can't do that kind of `return` for async function `getCount`. My suggestion is to switch to `promise` or `await async` for better code.

```
module.exports.getCount = function(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // set callback as promise function
    User.countDocuments({}, function(err,count){
      if (err) { 
        reject(err);
      }

      console.log(count)    // WORKS FINE
      resolve(count); // resolve with count value
    })
  })  
}

module.exports.FB_updateUserID = function(facebookUserID){  
  return this.getCount();
}

// facebooklogin.js
User.FB_updateUserID(req.body.facebookUserID).then(updatedUser => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(updatedUser); 
});
```

or using `await`

```
// facebooklogin.js
try {
  const updatedUser = await User.FB_updateUserID(req.body.facebookUserID);
  console.log(updatedUser); 
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}
```